# Function applied to an object outside its domain

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have a function $g \in B \to A$, where B does not contain the empty set, what is the value of $g (\emptyset)$? I am tempted to say that $g(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but I do not know what the formal reason for this would be.

My reason for wanting to know this is that I want to calculate $A \setminus g(\emptyset)$. The question is therefore whether $A \setminus g(\emptyset) = A \setminus \emptyset$.

---

If, for any $A$ which is a subset of some set $V$, $g(A) = \{ g(x) \mid x \in A\}$, then $g(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, so that my supposition above is correct.

Comment: Usually if one puts a subset of the domain as the argument of a function one intends the image of that set through the function. You are correct as the image of the empty set is empty

Comment: So also for another object $m$ outside the domain of $g$ which is not the empty set, $g(m) = \emptyset$? The reason I ask is that I wouldn't be sure how to calculate $A\setminus g(m)$ in that case.

Comment: No, not any other element of the domain but rather any subset of the domain

Comment: Ah, that's the confusion. The function applies to subsets of the domain. So when $m$ is not in the domain of $g$, $g(m)$ is simply not well-formed, right?

Comment: I would look at the definition of image of a subset https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics). This is regarded as an abuse of notation since in the round brackets one is supposed to find an argument for the function which can only be an element of the domain. For the image one is not feeding the function an argument of the domain but rather a subset and is given another subset in the codomain